# Swift 3: add a double value to an array increase a decimal

Tags: arrays, swift, decimal

When I put this in my code in swift 3 with xcode :

```
myarray.append(99.1)
```

I have following result when I use `print(myarray)` command for my array:

> 99.099999999999994

I would like to have only `99.1` no more. How can I add a value like `99.1` without being transform to the longer value in an array?

Comment: http://floating-point-gui.de

Comment: Doubles and Floats will both lose precision. Try taking a look at NSDecimalNumber. We deal with money in our app and it's a bit more complicated to use but is the only way to go.